# PHP - Assign a value to a variable only if it's not false

Tags: php

I would like to know if there is a more simple way to assign a value to my variable :

```
$foo = bar($baz);      // 'NULL' or '0' or '1' or '2' or ...
$foo = $foo ?: 0;     // '0' or '1' or '2' or ...
```

My problem is that `$foo` can be either `NULL` or a positive integer, including `0`.

I want it to become `0` if its value is `NULL`, and to keep its value if it is not.

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT

I cannot merge the 2 lines so my question is only for the second one.

Comment: If you can't merge those two lines, then how much simpler does this need to be…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$foo = intval( $foo );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
if (null === ($foo = bar($baz)))
    $foo = 0;
```

If you are using PHP7 then you can do like this:

```
$foo = bar($baz) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try :

```
$foo = is_null($foo) ? 0: $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot merge the 2 lines so my question is only for the second one.

But it's a workable solution:

```
$foo = bar($baz) ?: 0;
```

Short version of ternary operator means directly: take value from condition if it won't be converted to false

P.S. The better way would be to delegate that logic to function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$foo = ($foo = bar($baz)) ? $foo : 0;

Answer (score 0):

Although old question... I believe the question is not answered :-).
Yet I think the answer is no.
Consider:

```
$i = 3;
$i = strpos('xyz','a'); // Now $i === false.
```

Rather, if strpos() returned false, $i should still be 3.

```
$i = intval( strpos ( 'xyz', 'a' ) ) // $i = 0 
//OR
$i = strpos ( 'xyz', 'a' ) ?: $i     // $i = 3, but not working if strpos finds 'a'  
$i = strpos ( 'xyz', 'a' ) ?? $i     // $i = false, as ?? works on NULL
```

I think the question was, is there a simpler way of doing this:

```
if (($j = strpos('xyz','a')) !== false) $i = $j;
```

...and I haven't seen it.